# How to select nodes that has X as descendant using xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

consider following example:

```
<root>
   <instruments>
      <flute>
         <baz>bazik</baz>
      </flute>
      <guitar>
         <deep>
            <baz>more bazik</baz>
         </deep>
      </guitar>
      <drum>
         <foo>fooled</foo>
      </drum>
   </instruments>
</root>
```

I want to select `flute` and `guitar` because they both contain `baz` as a descendant node. How can I do that?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

the key is to use predicate `[descendant::baz]`

so the expression can be

```
/root/instruments/*[descendant::baz]
```

Comment: Or, for short: `/root/instruments/*[.//baz]`

Comment: How would I extract `<instruments>
      <flute>
         <baz>bazik</baz>
      </flute>
      <guitar>
         <deep>
            <baz>more bazik</baz>
         </deep>
      </guitar>
      <drum>
         <foo>fooled</foo>
      </drum>
   </instruments>`

Comment: @Arthur Eirich --if you post a question I will respond with the code to do it